# How to disable the default inferred types in Typescript from plain Javascript files?

Tags: typescript

I have a plain Javascript file that looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: '****',
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PW || '****',
    database: '****',
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
  },
  production: {
    username: '****',
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PW,
    database: '****',
    host: '****',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      idle: 3000,
    },
    ssl: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: '****',
    },
  },
}
```

These are constructor options to a [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) constructor.

Now when I'm trying to import the file I want to have it typed in Typescript. So I made a declaration in one of my declaration files which looks like:

```
import { Options } from 'sequelize'

declare module '@/db/config' {
  export const development: Options
  export const dev: Options
  export const staging: Options
  export const production: Options
}
```

Now when I try to use the import of this file like this:

```
import dbConfig from '@/db/config'

const sequelize = new Sequelize({ ...dbConfig.development, database: '****' })
```

I get the following TS error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(options?: Options): Sequelize', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ database: string; username: string; password: string; host: string; dialect: string; logging: boolean; } | { database: string; dialect?: Dialect; dialectModule?: object; dialectModulePath?: string; ... 31 more ...; benchmark?: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
      Type '{ database: string; username: string; password: string; host: string; dialect: string; logging: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
        Types of property 'dialect' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Dialect'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(uri: string, options?: Options): Sequelize', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ database: string; username: string; password: string; host: string; dialect: string; logging: boolean; } | { database: string; dialect?: Dialect; dialectModule?: object; dialectModulePath?: string; ... 31 more ...; benchmark?: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type '{ database: string; username: string; password: string; host: string; dialect: string; logging: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
```

It seems like the TS compiler combines the type declaration that I had created with an inferred type when reading the file. I'm using VSCode and it also shows 2 declarations; the one I created, and the one that is inferred. Because dialect is inferred as string and not as type Dialect it complains here.

Is there a way to tell the TS compiler to not infer the type definitions from the file?

I tried // @ts-nocheck and // @ts-ignore in the imported plain JS file but that did not work.